How to find bounds for $f^{(p-1)}$ derivative with bounds of $f^{(p)}$ and $f$ given?
I am working on exercise 5.3.9 of Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I. The problem is

Let $f^{(p)}$ exist on interval $I$, and let $M_k=\sup_{x\in I}\left\vert f^{(k)}(x)\right\vert$.(a) Let $I=[-a,a]$ show $|f'(x)|\leq\frac{M_0}a+\frac{x^2+x^2}{2a}M_2$, if $M_0$ and $M_2$ are finite.(b) If $M_0$ and $M_2$ are finite, then
$$
M_1\leq\begin{cases}2\sqrt{M_0M_2}&\#(I)\geq2\sqrt{M_0/M_2}\\ \sqrt{2M_0M_2}&I=\mathbb R\end{cases}
$$
Where $\#(I)$ is the length of $I$.(c) Show the $\sqrt2$ and $2$ in (b) are optimal.
(d) Let $M_0$ and $M_p$ be finite, show that when $1\leq k\leq p$, $M_k$ is finite, and furthermore, we have Landau-Kolmogorov inequality
$$
M_k\leq2^{k(p-k)/2}M_0^{1-k/p}M_p^{k/p}
$$
Hint: for (d), use induction, (b) and (b) of exercise 5.3.6, which is:

Let $f\in C^{(n)}(-1,+1)$ and $M_0((-1,1))\leq1$. Let $m_k(I)=\inf_{x\in I}\left\vert f^{(k)}(x)\right\vert$ where $I$ is a subinterval of $(-1,1)$. Then there is
$$
m_k(I)\leq\frac{2^{k(k+1)/2}k^k}{\lambda^k}
$$


I've already proved (b) of 5.3.6 and (a)-(c) of this exercise, but I have trouble showing (d).
My trial.
Induct on $p$. When $p=1$, $k$ can only be $1$, so $M_k=M_p$ is bounded, and the inequality becomes
$$
M_1\leq 2^0M_0^0M_1^1=M_1
$$
Which is a tautology. Now suppose $p-1$ case holds, we want to prove $p$ case.
The $k=p$ case is trivial as $M_p\leq M_p$. By inductive hypothesis, the $p-1$ case states that as long as $M_{p-1}$ is finite, for $1\leq k\leq p-1$ there is
$$
M_k\leq2^{k(p-k-1)/2}M_0^{1-k/(p-1)}M_{p-1}^{k/(p-1)}
$$
So we shall prove
$$
2^{k(p-k-1)/2}M_0^{1-k/(p-1)}M_{p-1}^{k/(p-1)}\leq2^{k(p-k)/2}M_0^{1-k/p}M_p^{k/p}
$$
Which is reduced to
$$
\begin{align}
M_{p-1}^{k/(p-1)}&\leq 2^{k/2}M_0^{k/p(p-1)}M_p^{k/p}\\
M_{p-1}&\leq M_p^{1-1/p}M_0^{1/p}2^{(p-1)/2}
\end{align}
$$
I try to use (b) to show this:
$$
M_{p-1}^2\leq2M_{p-2}M_p\leq2M_p2^{(p-2)/2}M_0^{1/(p-1)}M_{p-1}^{(p-2)/(p-1)}
$$
Which can be reduced to exactly the inequality we want. However, there are two problems in this step, namely

$M_{p-1}\leq\sqrt{2M_{p-2}M_p}$ requires $M_{p-2}$ to be finite, to guarantee which we need $M_{p-1}$ be finite.
the upper bound of $M_{p-2}$ requires $M_{p-1}$ be finite, whence the inductive hypothesis can be used.

So I think the key problem is to prove $M_{p-1}$ is finite, or $M_{p-2}$ is finite, but I do not know how to achieve that. I think there may be something to do with the hint about (b) of exercise 5.3.6, but as it gives upper bounds to $\inf$ instead of $\sup$, I cannot think of a way to use that.
Any hint?

By replacing $f$ with $f/M_0$, you can assume that $M_0=1$. Let $x\in I$. The difficult case is when $I$ has infinite length. Let’s assume that. Then either $[x,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,x]$ is included in $I$. Say, the first. Let $J=[x,x+1]$. By the exercise in the hint, you have that $m_{p-1}(J)\le C_p$. Moreover, since $J$ is compact, there is $y\in J$ such that $|f^{(p-1)}(y)|=m_{p-1}$.
Now use the mean value theorem to get $$f^{(p-1)}(x)=f^{(p-1)}(y)+f^{(p)}(c)(x-y)$$
Taking the absolute value, you have that the right hand side is bounded by $C_p+M_p$.
If the interval has finite length, apply the mean value theorem with $x$ and $y$ the midpoint.
This shows that $M_{p-1}$ is finite.
